# Rails - same route for more than one of the same http methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way that it's possible for me to have the same URL for multiple actions (in different controllers) where the HTTP method is the same?

e.g.

```
get 'users/:username/profile' => 'users#profile', as: :user_profile
  put 'users/:username/profile' => 'users#avatar_upload', as: :edit_user_avatar
  post 'users/:username/profile' => 'users#update', as: :user_edit_profile
  post 'users/:username/profile' => 'userspayment#create', as: :add_user_payment_details
  post 'users/:username/profile' => 'userspayment#update', as: :user_edit_payment_details
```

Currently I have:

```
get 'users/:username/profile' => 'users#profile', as: :user_profile
  put 'users/:username/profile' => 'users#avatar_upload', as: :edit_user_avatar
  post 'users/:username/profile' => 'users#update', as: :user_edit_profile
  post 'users/:username/profile/payment-details/add' => 'userspayment#create', as: :add_user_payment_details
  post 'users/:username/profile/payment-details/edit' => 'userspayment#update', as: :user_edit_payment_details
```

But when I run the `add` or `update` method in `userspayment_controller.rb` I'm rendering the `users/profile` view afterwards and the URL changes. I don't want to redirect because the add and update forms are in tabs and a redirect will make the first tab active. This is my `UserpaymentsController`:

```
class UserspaymentController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_user

  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      @user_payment_details = UsersPaymentDetails.new(users_payment_details_params)
      if @user_payment_details.save
        record_activity('Updated payment information.')
        format.html { render :template => "users/profile", :locals => { :user => @user }, notice: 'Payment details was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render(:file => Rails.root.join('public', '422'), :formats => [:html], :status => 422, :layout => false) }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      @user_payment_details = UsersPaymentDetails.find_by(user_id: @user.id)
      if @user_payment_details.update(users_payment_details_params)
        record_activity('Updated payment information.')
        format.html { render :template => "users/profile", :locals => { :user => @user }, notice: 'Payment details was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render(:file => Rails.root.join('public', '422'), :formats => [:html], :status => 422, :layout => false) }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def users_payment_details_params
      params.require(:users_payment_details).permit(:bank, :branch, :code, :account, :holder, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Think about it, if you post to an url, then how should your router know to which controller#action it must go? What you maybe could do is if you know what it renders, trigger an click on the matching tab.

Comment: I wasn't sure if having different route names would help. Will try to trigger the click instead.

Comment: Also, you need to use `PUT` method on update. Idempotence...

Comment: I'm using ```PUT``` to update the user avatar without a page redirect. How can I make the user personal details use ```PUT``` too? It's in the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other comment stated, your approach isn't going to work. However...

In your `routes.rb`, you could do:

```
resources :users, param: :user_name

scope :users do 
  patch ':user_name/*other', controller: :users, action: :update
  get   ':user_name/*other', controller: :users, action: :show
  post  ':user_name/*other', controller: :users, action: :create
end
```

Which will give you:

```
    users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:user_name/edit(.:format)       users#edit
     user GET    /users/:user_name(.:format)            users#show
          PATCH  /users/:user_name(.:format)            users#update
          PUT    /users/:user_name(.:format)            users#update
          DELETE /users/:user_name(.:format)            users#destroy
          PATCH  /users/:user_name/*other(.:format)     users#update
          GET    /users/:user_name/*other(.:format)     users#show
          POST   /users/:user_name/*other(.:format)     users#create
```

Now, when you have a `url` like:

```
/users/foo-bar/profile
```

it will route to the appropriate `update`, `show`, or `create` action (depending on the HTTP verb) with a `params[:other]` equal to `profile`.

In your `ApplicationController`, you could do something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

    def call_action_service
      action_service.call params.except(:controller, :action, :other)
    end

    def action_service
      "#{params[:controller].camelize}::#{params[:other].gsub('-','_').camelize}::#{params[:action].camelize}Service".constantize
    end

end
```

So, if you did a `get` on `/users/foo-bar/profile`, then `action_service` would resolve to:

```
Users::Profile::ShowService
```

And you could make your `UsersController` something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
      unless params[:other]
        # do regular show
      else
        call_action_service
      end
    end

    def update
      unless params[:other]
        # do regular update
      else
        call_action_service
      end
    end

    def create
      unless params[:other]
        # do regular create
      else
        call_action_service
      end
    end

  private 

end
```

You'll note that you have only the RESTful actions, now (`show`, `update`, `create`, etc.) and have done away with non-RESTful actions (like `profile`, and `avatar_upload`).

So, in the end, the following `HTTP verbs` and `url`s will call the services:

```
GET    /users/:user_name/profile                    == calls ==>   Users::Profile::ShowService
PATCH  /users/:user_name/profile                    == calls ==>   Users::Profile::UpdateService
PATCH  /users/:user_name/profile/avatar             == calls ==>   Users::Profile::Avatar::UpdateService
PATCH  /users/:user_name/profile/payment-details    == calls ==>   Users::Profile::PaymentDetails::UpdateService
POST   /users/:user_name/profile/payment-details    == calls ==>   Users::Profile::PaymentDetails::CreateService
```

If we continue with the example of making a `get` call to `/users/foo-bar/profile`, then you'll need a `Users::Profile::ShowService`:

```
#app/services/users/profile/show_service.rb
module Users
  module Profile
    class ShowService < ServiceBase 

      def call
        # do useful stuff
      end

    end
  end
end
```

You'll also need `ServiceBase`:

```
#app/services/service_base.rb
class ServiceBase

  attr_accessor *%w(
    args
  ).freeze

  class << self 

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call 
    end

  end

  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
  end

  def call
    # this is the fall back `call` method for all services
  end

end
```

To make generating your paths easier, you might do something like:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def other_user_path(other)
    user_path(@user.name).send(:<<, "/#{other}")
  end

end
```

So that you could do something like:

```
other_user_path('profile/payment-details')
```

and get

```
/users/foo-bar/profile/payment-details
```

Naturally, you'll want to add back in your `respond_to do |format|` stuff. But, I'll leave that to you to fiddle with.

Comment: Thanks, @jvillian! I didn't expect such a details answer but this is perfect. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Sure thing! Happy it helped. Welcome to the world of services and skinny controllers.